# Can we use this expression

Tags: word-usage

Is this OK to use the following:

> Looking into the photograph the girl said, "It's me before 5 years."

Comment: Can you provide the context? What does the photograph actually depict?

Comment: If today I am 21; this me 5 years ago (2009); this is me before I was 5 (anytime between 1993 and 1996). For ages we tend to say: *I am 21* or *I am 21 years old*. *I am 21 years* is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Looking at the photograph, the girl said, "this is me five years ago."

I think you mean the girl sees an old photo of herself.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the photograph was of the girl taken at a time when she was younger than 5 years old, she might say:

"It's me before I was 5"

As choster says - the context isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes. The girl sees her old photograph.

Answer (score 0):

The least change would be

> Looking into the photograph the girl said, "It's me 5 years before (now)."

the 'now' could be left off and implied.